# How to remove series of lines in a file on hp unix using awk or sed or grep

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, hp-ux

My report looks like:

```
Report B566  company name .................................... Page 1

    Name    address   pin   


    John    ny        1111
    Dave    ma        1112
    ....    ....    ....   
    ....    ....    ....   
    ....    ....    ....   
Report B566  company name .................................... Page 2

    Name    address   pin   


    Barry    CA        5111
```

This way i have around 100 pages, i want to get rid of repetitive headers. i need a command in such way that if "Report B566" is found in the file all of them along with the next 6 lines should be removed and the outfile should contain only the data.

I'm working on HP-UNIX box. (ksh)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the first 6 lines? Including the `Report B566` it is only 5 lines to the first record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a counter and print based on when the counter is true.

```
$ awk '/Report/{c=6}!(c&&--c)' file
John    ny        1111
Dave    ma        1112
....    ....    ....
....    ....    ....
....    ....    ....
Barry    CA        5111
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution

```
sed '/Report/,+4d' file
```

This removes the report line and the four following lines, it's a really simple command.

Comment: @jaypal i have another query, can i post it here?

Comment: @jaypal  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915996/passing-variables-in-shell-script-hp-unix-box

Comment: @jaypal did you get to look into the question i've asked?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915996/awk-not-working-within-script-on-hp-unix-box

Comment: @jaypal this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930617/awk-usage-in-shell-script-hp-unix

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/Report/{G;/^(\S+\s+\S+\s).*\n\1/!{s/\n.*//;h;b};N;N;N;N;d}' file
```

Compare `Report` lines to the previous one and if they are the same remove it and the next five lines. If not the same store it and resume as usual.